# Reverse a dictionary order python

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a python dictionary as follows:

```
DictValue = {
'Event1': {},
'Event2': {
    'copy3': {
        'SourcePath': 'souce3',
        'DestPath': 'dest3',
        'Platform': u 'Debug|Win32'
    },
    'copy2': {
        'SourcePath': 'souce3',
        'DestPath': 'dest2',
        'Platform': u 'Debug|Win32'
    },
    'copy1': {
        'SourcePath': 'souce1',
        'DestPath': 'dest1',
        'Platform': u 'Debug|x64'
    },
    'copy5': {
        'SourcePath': 'souce5',
        'DestPath': 'dest5',
        'Platform': u 'Release|Win32'
    },
    'copy4': {
        'SourcePath': 'souce4',
        'DestPath': 'dest4',
        'Platform': u 'Release|x64'
    }
}
}
```

I want to sort the Dictionary value so that it should looks like

```
{
'Event1': {},
'Event2': {
    'copy1': {
        'SourcePath': 'souce1',
        'DestPath': 'dest1',
        'Platform': u 'Debug|Win32'
    },
    'copy2': {
        'SourcePath': 'souce2',
        'DestPath': 'dest2',
        'Platform': u 'Debug|Win32'
    },
    'copy3': {
        'SourcePath': 'souce3',
        'DestPath': 'dest3',
        'Platform': u 'Debug|x64'
    },
    'copy4': {
        'SourcePath': 'souce4',
        'DestPath': 'dest4',
        'Platform': u 'Release|Win32'
    },
    'copy5': {
        'SourcePath': 'souce5',
        'DestPath': 'dest5',
        'Platform': u 'Release|x64'
    }
}
​}
```

Is it possible? Please help. I'am using `python 2.6`

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries do not have any ordering. If you require ordering your options are:

- To use a list of tuples instead.
- Sorting the `.keys()` when you loop (or `.values()` or `.items()`, depending on your needs)
- Use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.